# How can a composed object refer to object it is composed inside?

Tags: python

I have following classes in my application.

```
class Command: 
    def __init__(self, command_id, command_name, exec_string):
        self.command_name = command_name
        self.exec_string = exec_string

class Checkpoint:
    def __init__(self, checkpoint_id, checkpoint_name, commands):
        self.checkpoint_id = checkpoint_id
        self.checkpoint_name = checkpoint_name
        self.commands = commands

class Job:
    def __init__(self, job_id, job_name, checkpoints):
        self.job_id = job_id
        self.job_name = job_name
        self.checkpoints = checkpoints
```

I also have executor classes as follows

```
class JobExecutor:
    def __init__(self, checkpoint_executor):
        self.checkpoint_executor = checkpoint_executor

    def execute_job(self, job):
        # set job state to running

        # run job
        for checkpoint in job.checkpoints:
            self.checkpoint_executor.execute_checkpoint(checkpoint)

class CheckpointExecutor:
    def __init__(self, command_executor):
        self.command_executor = command_executor

    def execute_checkpoint(self, checkpoint):
        # set checkpoint state to running

        # run checkpoint
        for command in checkpoint.commands:
            self.command_executor.execute_command(command)

class CommandExecutor:
    def run_process(self, exe): 
        import subprocess
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
            return stdout
        except FileNotFoundError as error:
            pass

    def execute_command(self, command):
        # set command state to running

        # run command
        output = run_process(command.exec_string.split()))

        if output:
            # set command state to completed
        else:
            # set command state to failed
```

Sample usage

```
command1 = Command(command_id = 1 , command_name = "echo", exec_string = "echo start")
command2 = Command(command_id = 2 , command_name = "list", exec_string = "ls -i")
command3 = Command(command_id = 3 , command_name = "wordcount", exec_string = "wc -l Decorator.ipynb")

checkpoint1 = Checkpoint(checkpoint_id = 1, checkpoint_name = "first_checkpoint", commands = [command1, command2])
checkpoint2 = Checkpoint(checkpoint_id = 2, checkpoint_name = "second_checkpoint", commands = [command3])

job = Job(job_id = 1, job_name = "unix tutorial", checkpoints = [checkpoint1, checkpoint2])

job_executor = JobExecutor(CheckpointExecutor(CommandExecutor()))
job_executor.execute_job(job)
```

Inside "execute_checkpoint" method I want to refer job object inside which this checkpoint is contained and inside "execute_command" method I want to refer checkpoint object inside which this command is contained. How can I do that without corrupting signature of execute methods?

Comment: The job could set itself as a attribute on all its checkpoints and likewise the checkpoints with the commands.

Comment: Won't that become a circular reference?

Comment: Yes but that only is an issue if these objects have a lot of churn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How "to refer job object inside which this checkpoint is contained"

You can add a field to refer to the parent and the assign to that field when the Job is created.

```
class Checkpoint:
    def __init__(self, checkpoint_id, checkpoint_name, commands):
        self.checkpoint_id = checkpoint_id
        self.checkpoint_name = checkpoint_name
        self.commands = commands
        self.parent = None                           # <== Placeholder          

class Job:
    def __init__(self, job_id, job_name, checkpoints):
        self.job_id = job_id
        self.job_name = job_name
        self.checkpoints = checkpoints
        for checkpoint in checkpoints:               # <== All checkpoints   
            checkpoint.parent = self                 # <== Store ref to parent
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wont this become a circular reference? I mean how GC will behave in such cases?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Yes, it does create a circular reference.  No, it isn't a problem.  Yes, GC will clean it up when there are no external references.  For earlier clean-up, it is possible to use weak references, but it probably isn't worth it.  Some form of back reference is intrinsic to the OP's use case (children needing to refer to the containing classes).